# Capybara accessing the same session from two threads

Tags: multithreading, selenium, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I have a ruby script that is running Capybara using selenium chrome driver.
The test navigates a website, at an unknown time a notification will appear that needs to be closed.

Is it possible to have a second thread that is polling the driver to check for the presence of the notification while the script continues perform the test.

I have tried a few different approaches, but I get errors such as `Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF)` which appears to be because the session/driver is not thread safe.

If this cannot be done, any ideas for dealing with this issue would be much appreciated. I would rather not have a piece of code I keep calling between actions, as I fear this would cause performance issues over time.

Comment: I think selenium has some "close all alerts" flag... But I might be wrong. Let me check docs

Comment: It's not an alert, it's an html notification that is part of the web app DOM.

Comment: Why does the notification need to be closed? Is that part of the test or a side affect of the website? If you leave it open, what happens to the website? Generally I try and work around side affects of the UI and only click/care about what is necessary. You know your application best, but sometimes waiting for and clicking an indeterministic ui event is a good way to get a hanging test suite.

Comment: It causes a flakey test. if the notification does not appear the test works fine, however if it does appear then the test can fail if it cannot click on the element.
And with a large number of tests it can have an affect on any number of tests, at random.
Unfortunately this is not an application I have input into developing, so I cannot change it's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a starting point, but not 100% of what you're looking for http://blog.jthoenes.net/2013/08/16/waiting-for-a-javascript-event-with-seleniumcapybara/